# TypeError: cannot read property of length undefined? - React Carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

Following this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1MYfu5YWHc&list=PLVwSdwIkTF50m5Fnd-_vSIrT8mvtfeZxe&index=8) exactly because I want to use this carousel on my website.

However I get the error "TypeError: cannot read property of undefined", even though the code is exactly same as tutorial and the tutorial instructor never encounters this error.

1. How do I solve this?
2. Why do I get this error and the tutorial instructor did not? finding it hard to understand how this happens - the video is only from December 2020

Thanks in advance.

Code below:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { CarouselData } from '../Data/CarouselData';
import {FaArrowAltCircleRight, FaArrowAltCircleLeft} from 'react-icons/fa';

export const Carousel = ({slides}) => {

    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
    const length = slides.length;

    const nextSlide = () => {
        setCurrent(current === length -1 ? 0 : current + 1)
    }
    const prevSlide = () => {
        setCurrent(current === length -1 ? 0 : current + 1);
    }

    console.log(current);
    if (!Array.isArray(slides) || slides.length <= 0){
        return null;
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <Section>
                <LeftArrow >
                    <FaArrowAltCircleLeft onClick={prevSlide}/>
                </LeftArrow>
                {CarouselData.map((slide, index) => {
                    return(
                        <img style={{width: "400px", height: "600px", borderRadius: "10px"}} src={slide.image} alt="image" />
                    )
                })}
                <RightArrow >
                    <FaArrowAltCircleRight onClick={nextSlide}/>
                </RightArrow>
            </Section>
            
        </div>
    )
}

const Section = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
`
const LeftArrow = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 32px;
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: white;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;

`
const RightArrow = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 32px;
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: white;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
`
const Image = styled.div`
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 10px;
`
```

P.S. - if a codesandbox is needed I will make one however this is a small codefile and small issue so did not think was needed

Comment: Is `slides` ever undefined here?

Comment: And a codesandbox is always helpful.  Much of the time you'll discover your problem while creating the codesandbox, and you won't even need to write the question.

Comment: Will make one now then!

Comment: can you also show how you're sending slides as a prop?

Comment: But my guess is that you just need to protect against undefined slides in the `length = slides.length` thing.

Comment: Lmao Chris I literally just solved it by creating a codesandbox fair enough you were not wrong! - David You are on the ball I had forgotten to add slides as  a prop on my function in the portfolio page I was displaying it in

Comment: It seems like you are not passing `slides` props from it's parent component.

Answer (score 0):

The error came from not putting slides as a prop in my parent component PortfolioPage.

See code below - before the the parenthesis of my function PortfolioPage was empty - hence why slides was undefined now once slides is added it is defined.

```
export const PortfolioPage = (slides) => {
    return (
        <div style={{ height: "100vh"}}>
            <Container>
                <Grid container>
                    <Grid item md={6}>
                        <TopSection>

                        </TopSection>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item md={6}>
                        <BottomSection>
                            <Carousel slides={CarouselData}/>

                            
                    

                        </BottomSection>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
```